# Is it possible to set a default Outlook profile per machine?

Tags: powershell, outlook, gpo

Dear people on Stackoverflow,

is it possible to set a default Outlook profile per machine, so for example that it doesn't matter which user logs in at the machine, they can only access one particular mail profile.

Thank you all for helping!

Comment: See [Create a new profile in Outlook for all users in a domain](https://www.edbmails.com/pages/new-profile-in-outlook-for-all-users.html)

Comment: Before posting, you should [these guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254573/979052)

Answer (score 1):

No, Outlook profiles are stored on the per user (HKCU) basis.